# How to use axi dma kernel module in custom application in petalinux?

Tags: yocto, xilinx, vivado, zynq, petalinux

I am trying to build the axidma-benchmark application with the Xilinx-axidma driver [(Github repo)](https://github.com/bperez77/xilinx_axidma) provided by [bperez77](https://github.com/bperez77).

I am using Petalinux 20.2 to build Linux for my custom project.
In the new version of the kernel, some functions are changed and I get some errors when running `petalinux-build`. I changed the driver files as mentioned [here](https://github.com/bperez77/xilinx_axidma/issues/127) and build the kernel module successfully.

In the following, I create the custom application by running:

```
petalinux-create -t apps --name axidma-benchmark --enable
```

Then I copy the application files into the recipes-apps directory and append all C and header files to the SRC_URI List in the axidma-benchmark.bb as:

```
SRC_URI = "file://axidma-benchmark.c \
       file://axidma_ioctl.h \
       file://conversion.h \
       file://libaxidma.h \
       file://util.c \
       file://util.h \
       file://Makefile \
      "
```

Then I add `APP_OBJS += util.o` to the Makefile and build the application by running:

```
petalinux-build -c axidma-benchmark
```

But I got these errors:

> ERROR: axidma-benchmark-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
> ERROR: axidma-benchmark-1.0-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.21635' failed with exit code 1:
> aarch64-xilinx-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a72.cortex-a53 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -o axidma-benchmark axidma-benchmark.o util.o -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: axidma-benchmark.o: in function `main': /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:491: undefined reference to` axidma_init'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:499: undefined reference to `axidma_malloc' /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:505: undefined reference to` axidma_malloc'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:514: undefined reference to `axidma_get_vdma_tx' /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:515: undefined reference to` axidma_get_vdma_rx'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: axidma-benchmark.o: in function `single_transfer_test': /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:396: undefined reference to` axidma_twoway_transfer'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: axidma-benchmark.o: in function `main': /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:558: undefined reference to` axidma_free'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:560: undefined reference to `axidma_free' /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:562: undefined reference to` axidma_destroy'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:519: undefined reference to `axidma_get_dma_tx' /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:520: undefined reference to` axidma_get_dma_rx'
> /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-xilinx-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-xilinx-linux/gcc/aarch64-xilinx-linux/9.2.0/ld: axidma-benchmark.o: in function `time_dma': /usr/src/debug/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/axidma-benchmark.c:426: undefined reference to` axidma_twoway_transfer'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:12: axidma-benchmark] Error 1
> WARNING: /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.21635:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/fpgaws/projects/DevelopmentLab/build/apu/ultrazed7ev/build/tmp/work/aarch64-xilinx-linux/axidma-benchmark/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.21635

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten to add the `libaxidma.c` files into the file directory. By adding this file application was built successfully.

Update:
You can access the final version of my code via [this link](https://gitlab.gnome.org/HosseinBeheshti/UlteraZed7EV/-/tree/master/petalinux/xilinx_axidma).
If you have any problems, please let me know.